# GCC gives "--: unknown option"

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile the current code: https://github.com/Cyan4973/zstd

But when running the "make" command I get:

```
user@pc:~/dev/zstd$ make
make -C programs
make[1]: Entering directory `~/dev/zstd/programs'
cc      -I../lib -DZSTD_VERSION=\"0.4.6\" -I../lib/legacy -I./legacy -DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1 -O3   -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wstrict-aliasing=1   ../lib/zstd_compress.c ../lib/zstd_decompress.c ../lib/fse.c ../lib/huff0.c ../lib/legacy/zstd_v01.c ../lib/legacy/zstd_v02.c ../lib/legacy/zstd_v03.c ../lib/zstd_buffered.c zstdcli.c fileio.c legacy/fileio_legacy.c bench.c xxhash.c datagen.c -o zstd
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/sh: --: unknown option
/tmp/ccTBDu2H.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [zstd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `~/dev/zstd/programs'
make: *** [zstdprogram] Error 2
```

I checked the Makefile and does not contain any "--", also `/system/bin/sh` is not in my computer, and if I copy `/bin/sh` there it does not change anything.

Debugging the makefile with `make -d` also does not give any extra info on the problem.

Any ideas?

I have ubuntu 12.04.

**EDIT: I discovered it is GCC 4.6.4 giving the error. Witch is not descriptive at all...**

**EDIT2: I fixed it by using `clang` in the compilation process (a newer GCC should also fix it), however I leave the question open since I have still no clue what error GCC has. Also it may be useful for future people having the same problem.**

Comment: Show your `Makefile`. What is `CC` there?

Comment: what's your gcc version? README file says it was compiled with gcc 4.8.4. I have 4.8.4 and it works like a charm.

Comment: I am using "gcc version 4.6.4". Maybe that is the problem. However I am still guessing what is failing that GCC does not understand. I managed to compile it with clang though

Comment: Show your `Makefile` and the sources being compiled. `tree` output of the project directory might also help.

Comment: My Makefile is the Makefile in the repository, no changes done there at all.

Comment: what's strange is that Travis CI environment uses `gcc 4.6.3`, and yet it works perfectly for them : 
https://travis-ci.org/Cyan4973/zstd/jobs/103085036

It could be an issue related to your local system, maybe the way `/bin/sh` is invoked. Or maybe the way `cc` is translated on your system (try typing `cc` in a terminal to check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, **the issue and solution are not related to GCC at all**.

I had a script in my `~ /bin/` folder called `as`. So instead of using the `as` (assembler compiler) application, was using the script instead (A script I created long time ago as an alias to `adb shell`). 
This lead to a bunch of error outputted when calling GCC, but just because GCC is calling the assembler at some point... Thats all.

So a very silly error.

*NOTE TO SELF: Check if the command already exists before overwritting it with something in ~/bin/.*

Answer (score 0):

If this is a cross-compiling, perhaps you have mixed host and target tools. This may happen when the host tools are used instead of target tools for processing of the target binaries (i.e. linking object files).

Comment: I am not cross compiling... I know looks like it is compiling to Android mode (/system/bin/sh), but it is not the case.